# CosmosDB MongoDB API: New query is hidden

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am working on CosmosDB MongoDB API. I want to find the RU Cost for the query which I performed.  I cant find anywhere "New Query" button anywhere.

[image]

Is there anyway how to find the RU cost for the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could view the RUs Cost in the Shell:

[image]

Or you could execute query as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new query by clicking three dots icon and opening the dialog and then New Query. Find the below image

[image]

you have the new Shell option below on the same dialog pane where you can execute the query and find the RU costed.